# Retreive Old Firefox Bookmarks After Formatting

Tags: bookmarks, firefox, windows-installation

I have recently formatted my Laptop. However I forgot to export my bookmarks before formatting .What I have now is a folder named as Windows.old ..... but I don't know how to recover my lost bookmarks. 
Is there a way so that I can get my old bookmarks ..... i.e. I could import my old bookmarks .... into the new installation ?

Answer (score 2):

The folder Windows.old contains your previous Windows installation. Its presence means that you have not formatted the hard disk, but have rather reinstalled Windows as a new installation in the unformatted disk.

If I am right about that misuse of the term "formatting", then there is still hope. Your bookmarks may still exist somewhere on the disk.

Search your hard disk for a file named `bookmarks.html`. You have not specified your Windows version, but in Vista or 7 you will find it in :
`C:\Users\[user-name]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[profile-name].default`.

There might be several versions of it, if you have reinstalled Firefox and were lucky enough for it to have picked up a different profile name the second time. If there is only one, then Firefox has probably over-written it (verify, just in case).

Verify that this file contains your old bookmarks - you can just double-click on it to open in a browser.

Now follow the instructions in [Import bookmarks](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Import_bookmarks). For Firefox 3:
Menu Bookmarks -> Organize Bookmarks -> Import and Backup -> Import HTML... -> from an HTML File.

Browse to the folder containing the file, select bookmarks.html and click "open". The imported bookmarks will be added to your existing bookmarks.

Comment: thnx buddy ..... I have got my problem solved ....The old bookmarks were lying in the path u had mentioned .....but in the folder created for windows.old

Comment: moreover the extension of the file was not .html .

Comment: It was .json and such files exist due to the backup files created by Mozilla Firefox !!!!

Comment: You were really lucky : I don't have a .json in my Firefox profile.

Comment: u might hv asked firefox not to backup ur book marks ....

Answer (score -1):

If anyone else has this problem with newer versions of Windows, you may encounter a super annoying .jsonlz4 file.     Here is how to restore the bookmarks using that annoying file.

After spending hours and hours searching and searching how to decompress the stupid jsonlz4 file so I could recover my bookmarks from a previous backup (after my computer crashed and windows had to be reinstalled).....

it turns out that you dont need to decompress it at all.

It all seemed so complicated, and there are a million answers out there, including crazy scripting and all kinds of crazy stuff.     But its actually SUPER RIDICULOUSLY simple...

If you HAVE your stupid jsonlz4 file, here's ALL you have to do.....

Go to "view all bookmarks", go to "restore", and select the stupid jsonlz4 file.    BOOM!   BOOKMARKS RESTORED!!!!!!!!

I hope this post saves someone from the agony I had to go through, and the (what I thought was) complete devastation at the loss of my very important and enormous collection of bookmarks.

Lesson learned though.... I'll certainly be making a backup!

Comment: Did you notice that jsonlz4 is the same as your user name? Anybody else looking for this file won't find it, so your answer is useless.